# In a Python Poetry project, what's the difference between {include = "b", from = "a"} and {include = "a/b"} in the packages section?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging, python-poetry

I'm trying to build a Python package using Poetry and have some sub-packages I need to include.

Using the `include` directive in pyproject.toml, I'm struggling to understand what's the difference between this:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
...
packages = [
    {include = "b", from = "a"},
]
```

and this:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
...
packages = [
    {include = "a/b"},
]
```

It seems to give the exact same result. When would I use one over the other?

Comment: A good programming language gives you multiple ways to shoot yourself in the foot. The difference is described [here](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/). I suspect they behave the same way if your directory structure happens to be arranged in a certain way.